# What are the key differences between Hyperledger Fabric and Hyperledger Indy (Sovrin)

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I have some experience with Hyperledger Fabric. It is a private permissioned blockchain used for many use cases. Hyperledger Indy on the other hand is used primary for decentralized identity management. I like to know if there is any way to know the key differences between the two projects. Is it possible to customize Hyperledger Fabric to perform similar to Hyperledger Indy for identity management cases?

Answer (score 5):

The difference is Fabric is stable (Active stage) and made for general-purpose. And Fabric is not accessible anonymously when Indy is publicly accessible.

[Indy is still in Incubation stage](https://wiki.hyperledger.org/) as of Dec 15, 2017. It seems to have fewer people working on. It also has limited documentations and code samples.

You can try using [Indy SDK](https://github.com/hyperledger/indy-sdk) to simulate sovrin identity solution on Fabric. But I don't think the SDK is production-ready yet.

Comment: As of my comment, IndySDK is production ready.   It is used in several apps including mobile apps.